# IE 10 open in multilple windows

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, internet-explorer-10

When I open Internet Explorer Window it opens a new window in first time... and the IE icon in task bar is filled with IE windows.  If I want to open another IE window, I have only 2 choices :

1. Open New window using File menu or
2. Right click IE Window on task bar and clicking IE.

Any one tell me how to open new IE window when first IE window is open, like opening multiple IE windows by clicking IE icon in taskbar?

Simply I want IE icon should be shown on Taskbar even mutiple IE windows open (Just like Vista and XP)

Comment: If you launch IE through the Start Menu it will launch a new window and instance of IE.

Comment: Try Shift Left-click on the taskbar icon

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can simply open a new tab, then pull the tab off of the tabs bar and it will create its own window.